# android app Login with telegram bot

Tags: android, telegram-bot

hi guys i find this [site](https://telegranted.me/) and i want to use it on my app basically this site is not design for apps but i think i can do it and this site working like this:when you register your app on this site then you have a link and when a user with telegram installed on phone he goes on a bot on telegram and when you press /start the link sites give you for login users goes to the site you gave the site with the information of the user like name and id i create a DeepLink for my app and its working i test it but i dont know why the link is not working on browser or webView sorry for bad english here is the login [Url](https://oauth.telegranted.me/auth?app_id=4f62c1c0-2c0d-42ab-9008-257b9b07479c) and this is the response

```
https://www.google.com/?status=success&user_id=38962624&first_name=na&last_name=null&username=aa&avatarUrl=https://img.telegranted.me/38962624.png&validation=0b397f29ce72afb7b37465421d36e9c0c1d009c0e8ebc20d6ab2d121186531cb
```

i test my deeplink and its working but this is the code
my manifest for deeplink

```xml
<activity
        android:name="app.mma.PokerInfo.LinkActivity"
        android:label="link" >
        <intent-filter android:label="filter_http_activity" android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="phelper.online"
                android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />
            <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:label="filter_link_activity">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos” -->
            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="phelper.online" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and this is my webView code

```java
wv.loadUrl("https://oauth.telegranted.me/auth?app_id=4f62c1c0-2c0d-");

String string = wv.getUrl();
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        boolean isLocalUrl = false;

        if (url.contains("phelper.online")) {
            isLocalUrl = true;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if (isLocalUrl)
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```

I hope you get the idea
**UPDATE**:
Telegram.me added the login system [read more](https://telegram.org/blog/login)